# Find shortest separable path in a colored graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given a directed graph $G$ and each of its edges is colored either red or blue, we want to find the shortest path from some vertex $s$ to some other vertex $t$.

Our path must however be separable by which we mean it must consist of first some number (possibly 0) of red edges and after that only blue edges.

I'm not allowed to use BFS (instead we are given an optimized program $P$ that, given as input a directed graph $G=(V,E)$ as well as two vertices $s,t \in V$, outputs the shortest path between them).

What I have in mind is have two graphs $G_B$​ and $G_R$​ together to create a new graph that I can run $P$ on.

Am I on the right track? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I would 1) compute the subgraph of only red vertices.  2) I would find the set of red nodes that are exactly $o$ steps from the vertex $s$ in the red subgraph.  3) Then I would find the set of blue nodes in the original graph that are adjacent to your set of red nodes.  4) Then I'd use BFS to find which of these blue vertices is closest to $t$.  5) Then concatenate the paths so found.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork So I'm not allowed to use BFS for this problem, but I think if I use $P$ instead (as described in the question), then that might just work.

Comment: Sure.  Try it...

Answer (score 1):

For each $v\in V$, find the shortest path in subgraph $G_R$ from $s$ to $v$ and its length (possibly $0$ or infinite), and find the shortest path in subgraph $G_B$ from $v$ to $t$ and its length.

Choose the $v^* \in V$ where the path length in $G_R$ from $s$ to $v^*$ plus the path length in $G_B$ from $v^*$ to $t$ is the shortest.